# Getting light curves from Kepler/K2

Tags: data-analysis, kepler

Hello I'd like to ask what are steps to get a light curve wfrom Kepler/K2 database. Let's say I'd need to get light curves of 10 random K type stars. How should I access the databases and what should I do next??

Comment: What is it  about the K2 databases access (e.g. this form)  that is https://archive.stsci.edu/k2/epic/search.php puzzling. Can you not just select a temperature range and take the first 10 objects (if you are truly interested in a random sample)?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Kepler/K2 MAST database https://archive.stsci.edu/kepler/data_search/search.php or https://archive.stsci.edu/k2/epic/search.php

Search on a temperature ($T_{\rm eff}$) range: e.g. for K-stars  4500 .. 5200

A (big) list of objects will be found and presented to you in a table. Mark the ones you want (all the Kepler objects should have available data, but not all the K2 ones will unless you limit your search to the earlier K2 campaigns) and then click on the "submit marked data for retrieval from STDADS"

It will then ask you to confirm that you want to download the data with various options to get at the data and a tick box list of what you want (including light curves).

Then once you've got the data you need to look at the FAQ and descriptions of data format etc. that can be found at the main Kepler archive pages https://archive.stsci.edu/kepler/

If on the other hand you just want to look at the light curves then you can do that without downloading the data by clicking on "plot marked light curves" on the search results page.